# How to use shortcodes in custom tinymce editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, shortcode

I have a plugin about custom terms and I'll create new terms page with custom tinymce editor of plugin. but my shortcodes doesn't work in this classic editor.
i tried unable all other plugins and unable wp classic editor but doesn't work. if i use shortcode to any empty page or post then there is not problem. should I enable any wp code for example like this "add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');"

This is my shortcode.

```
function sc_smAciklama_fonk() {
ob_start();
    smAciklama();
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('sc_smAciklama', 'sc_smAciklama_fonk');
```

And my usage [sc_smAciklama]

This is my function:

```
function smAciklama(){
?>
<ul class="product-features-list-aciklama">
    <li>
        bla bla bla
    </li>
    <li>
        bla bla bla
    </li>
</ul>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Your shortcode should work.  Please post the code for your shortcode.

Comment: edited my question. please check it

Comment: Please post the code for the function, smAciklama, and tell us what you are expecting it to do.  I'm assuming when you use the shortcode, nothing happens at all?

Comment: it is just a html list and i should use it on another page too. i want to use shortcode for not to write again this list

Comment: Please, I need to see the function to rule out possible causes.  You can replace any sensitive text with something else.

Comment: ok i added function code. you can check.

Comment: Looks good.  I would use another plugin to add your custom tinymce editor, like Advanced Custom Fields.  Then, in the template file, use the function provided by that plugin, the_field(), to display the contents of the editor on the page.  The shortcode should work fine if you do that.